# Python - subprocess I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, subprocess

I have tried with the class below, execute commands in sequence with subporcess module in python2.6.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class BaculaActions():

    def __init__(self):
        self.console = Popen(["bconsole"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

    def run_job(self, jobname, level):
        run = self.console.communicate("run job=%s level=%s yes" % (jobname, level))
        return(run)

    def del_jobid(self, jobid):
        delete = self.console.communicate("delete jobid=%s" % (jobid))
        return(delete)
```

However, if I try the following code, I get the error: 
ValueError: I / O operation on closed file

```
from pconsole import BaculaActions

myconsole = BaculaActions()

run = myconsole.run_job("xxxxx-data", "incremental")
delete = myconsole.del_jobid(25487)
```

Anyone have idea what can be wrong? 
I thank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual says it all really:

```
Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, 
until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
```

After you run the first command and get the result, the 'bconsole' process has *terminated*, the pipes are closed and hence the error on the second `communicate` call.

Comment: @isdeve This way then, the only solution would be for each command I need to run, I instantiate 'mysconsole' again? Another doubt, since Popen does not have a "method" close the process I start from it are "lost" in the system?

Comment: The process you start is not lost, it's terminates (i.e. closes). So you have two options: run 'bconsole' for every command you want to send and use `communicate` - which is the safest way to do it, or if 'bconsole' takes too long to startup everytime, and _if_ you know exactly how much output is generated by each command you send, you can write commands to stdin directly and read the expected number of lines from stdout/stderr - however, it's easy to deadlock and you need to know what you are doing in this case.

Comment: @adinanp: you probably want `pexpect` module, to communicate with the child process interactively as if in a terminal. See [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who somehow tried to help me.
As a solution to the problem, I made the following:

```
class BaculaActions():

    def console(self):
        return(Popen(["bconsole"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE))

    def run_job(self, jobname, level):
        run = self.console().communicate("run job=%s level=%s yes" % (jobname, level))
        return(run)

    def del_jobid(self, jobid):
        delete = self.console().communicate("delete jobid=%s" % (jobid))
        return(delete)

    def any_commands(self, command):
        any = self.console().communicate(command)
        return(any)
```

I created a method "console" and all other methods of my class I start.

This solved my problem.

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Better way is to do as below,

Any sub process initialization must be encapsulated with try catch, to handle resource allocation failures. Then return it, if success.

Before communicating, check whether channel is established (no errors) then communicate.

Best way is to keep "Popen" on the same place whereever you communicate.You may end up duplicating "Popen" two times. But this is safe.

Any unknown interrupts between “Popen” and “communicate”, will make your python job as hanging forever and will need manual kill. This is certainly what we don’t want in live